# Google-chrome crashes on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, xvfb

I am running chrome inside Xvfb session.
I am using Google Chrome 40.0.2214.91 version.
I am using the following commands to run it:

```
Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1920x1080x24 2> /tmp/xvfb.log &
google-chrome --disk-cache-dir=null -start-maximized $1 --enable-logging --v=1 2> /tmp/chrome.log &
```

I am getting the following errors in chrome log:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":17".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":17".
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[25037:25037:0311/075906:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(301)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[25037:25037:0311/075950:ERROR:x11_util.cc(82)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
```

Xvfb log does not show any error.

Comment: Related bug report: [CHECK failure: !g_in_x11_io_error_handler in chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=754421)

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into a similar problem. These commandline flags might help:

- `--disable-gpu-sandbox`
- `--disable-gpu`

Assuming you don't care about chrome using the GPU.